# Setting up Galera nodes with different server credentials

Tags: mysql, galera

Is it possible to have Galera nodes with a different username, password, and port?

Comment: Are you referring to _users_?  Or the replication itself?

Comment: I meant having credentials like,

Galera node1:
MySQL_username: node1
MySQL_pwd: root
port:3306

Galera node2:
MySQL_username: node2
MySQL_pwd: root
port:3308